# Resize to fit in a box and set background to black on "empty" part

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to obtain this result: **fixed box size** (133x100), the image should be resized **but not stretched** to fit inside that box, the empty space should be filled with black.

I'm actually trying with this command:

```
convert -background black -gravity center -extent 133x100 from.jpg to.jpg
```

However instead of fitting the image inside the requested box, I obtain a crop of the image.
How to obtain the requested result? I'm digging into documentation but there are a lot of options and I still didn't find (I think) the one that I require.

Comment: Related: aspect ratio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672830/how-to-resize-an-image-in-imagemagick-but-keep-an-aspect-ratio-constant

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like I've found the solution by myself with this link: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#fit_summery

And this code solved my issue:

```
convert from.jpg -thumbnail 133x100 -background black -gravity center -extent 133x100 to.jpg
```